# Custom C# Script and Security using CodeDom

Tags: c#

I'm making a piece of rendering software and I want to make the tools it encompasses extensible. I've built a UI that lets the user write custom C# functions for blending values. The functions (and accompanying values/constants) are added to a class and compiled using CodeDom, and the blend function is used from there. The functions must take the signature:

```
public float Blend(float baseValue, float value);
```

The trouble I'm having is that someone could very easily write a script that does all manner of malicious stuff. They know that this blend function is the entry point, but they could put any kind of code in there. Is there any way to restrict what assemblies are available to the CodeDom compiler? For example could I blacklist or whitelist certain assemblies? Could I prevent the script from accessing System.IO for example?

Regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen in other places where it is suggested to use AppDomain to sandbox your code.

The recommended approach for this is to execute the suspect code in a sandboxed AppDomain. Several reasons are given at [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shawnfa/5-reasons-to-choose-simple-sandboxing), and an even more important one is that most of the other potential approaches are deprecated as of .NET 4.0.

Comment: I have had colleagues use the AppDomain sandbox approach and just from overhearing their conversations it sounds like it introduces more problems than it solves.  I'm assuming they bumped into the same issues that lead MS to deem this approach flawed and deprecate the concept.